# Left Navigation - Group Similar Items into a Cascading Menu

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, design

I have a SharePoint 2013 instance where I need to group a set of links in the into a cascaded menu. The structure is shown below:

- Documents
- Support

  - IT Support
  - GP Support
  - Change Request
- Feedback

Once I click 'Support' the above mentioned 3 sub items should be listed out for selection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the "master page" (of your site or your site collection) for that and eventually adapt the CSS files.

As a general rule, developers recommend not to modify the standard files for CSS or master files, but to create a custom one and set ShPt to use those (in the Site Settings) instead of the original ones. The standard files may be overridden without warning by a ShPt update, and you would loose your editions.

EDIT: As for the js code to "expand/collapse" the sub-menu items, I guess you can make use of what is used by default ShPt in the grouped list views.